# Intersect two lists and count how many times each element overlaps

Tags: python, list, count, intersect

I am intersecting two lists with the following code:

```py
def interlist(lst1,lst2): 
    lst3 = list(filter(lambda x: x in lst1, lst2))

    return lst3
```

The thing, is that I want to count every intersection between `lst1` and `lst2`. The result should be a dictionary mapping elements to the number of times they overlap in both lists.

Comment: What do you mean by count? If you just want the length of the result you can just do `return len(lst3)`?

Comment: By *"count every intersection"* do you mean a dictionary showing how many times each element overlaps, or just the count of all of them, or just the number of distinct ones?

Comment: @kaya3 i mean a dictionary showing how many times each element overlaps

Comment: I think you need to clarify something: Say an element x exists twice in list1 and 3 times in list3. x is clearly in the intersection. How many x's are supposed to exist in your desired outcome?

Comment: @FatihAkici

Something like this:

lst1=["a" , "b" , "c"] 
lst2=["a" , "a" , "a" , "b", "b"] 
OUTPUT:{"a"=3, "b"=2} 
Something like how many times the elements from lst 1 repeats on lst2

Comment: Perfect! How about `lst2=["a" , "b" , "c"]`, `lst1=["a" , "a" , "a" , "b", "b"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and set intersection. The idea is to first count occurrences of each element in each list separately; then, the number of overlaps is the `min` of the two counts, for each element. This matches each occurrence in one list with a single occurrence in the other, so the `min` gives the number of matches that can be made. We only need to count elements which occur in both lists, so we take the intersection of the two key-sets.

If you want to count all matching pairs instead (i.e. each occurrence in `lst1` gets matched with every occurrence in `lst2`), replace `min(c1[k], c2[k])` with `c1[k] * c2[k]`. This counts the number of ways of choosing a pair with one occurrence from `lst1` and one from `lst2`.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_intersections(lst1, lst2):
    c1 = Counter(lst1)
    c2 = Counter(lst2)
    return { k: min(c1[k], c2[k]) for k in c1.keys() & c2.keys() }
```

Example:

```py
>>> lst1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'e']
>>> lst2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e']
>>> count_intersections(lst1, lst2)
{'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'e': 1}
```

This solution runs in O(m + n) time and uses at most O(m + n) auxiliary space, where m and n are the sizes of the two lists.

Comment: it works! 
It is possible to also returns something like this:

lst1=["a" , "b" , "c"]
lst2=["a" , "a" , "a" , "b", "b"]

{"a"=3, "b"=2}

Something like how many times the elements from lst 1 repeats on lst2

Comment: If you want to count all pairs of intersections, replace `min(c1[k], c2[k])` with `c1[k] * c2[k]`.

Comment: Thanks you it works. Could you kindly explain me what you code does. I kinda understant it but i am new in the programming world

Answer (score 0):

Per your clarification of:

If `lst1 = ["a", "b", "c"]`, `lst2 = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]` then `output = {"a": 3, "b": 2}`, you can simply do:

```
output = {}
for x in set(lst1):
    cnt = lst2.count(x)
    if cnt > 0:
        output[x] = cnt
```

Comment: This is a nice simple solution, but it takes O(mn) time. It's best to avoid using `.count` inside a loop, since that scans the whole list on every iteration; it's more efficient to do all the counts in one scan using a Counter.